With using VS Code Cmake Tools extension, how can I run program in external terminal?
With using VS Code Cmake Tools extension, how can I run program in external terminal?It seems like that Cmake tools extension not needing launch.json, tasks.json or setting.json can work, however program run in integrated terminal.
I create a setting.json in .vscode and type like
"cmake.debugConfig": {
"externalConsole": true
}
it can't work
I know that, what cmake is, So I'm talking about "Cmake Tools extension". I mean this as follow.How can program run in external terminal?How can program run in external terminal using that button?

I search the document of vscode-cmake in github but I can't find any solution, maybe I need to setup something like "cmake.testEnvironment"?
here link is microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools


I create a setting.json in .vscode and type like "cmake.debugConfig":
{ "externalConsole": true } it can't work

Use debug button and it will run in external terminal but not if you normally run your code.

Edit .vscode/settings.json
"cmake.debugConfig": {
    "externalConsole": true
}

Then use "debug" instead of "launch".

CMake doesn't run the program, it just simply generates a file that builds your program for example like makefile or ninjafile, then with those you can build your program. So overall, CMake just help you to build your program.
After successfully building your program, you can simply run the program by yourself in a terminal and if you want to run it after it does build it, you should create an environment for that by simply creating a task.json and call the task in launch.json (it was something like prelaunchtask or postlaunchDebug - see this)
Also see these two for better undrestanding:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations


I know that, what cmake is, So I'm talking about "Cmake Tools extension". I uploaded a picture to the question description.How can program run in external terminal using that button?I search the document of vscode-cmake in github but I can't find any solution, maybe I need to setup something like "cmake.testEnvironment"?
here link is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools

@RLPMSK I once run that launch and test and it was about the CMake itself, not the program (It was running/debugging the CmakeLists.txt). That test button is also related to google test with make. But I don't remember quite well, so don't make any decision on my words :).

@RLPMSK " uploaded a picture" - Don't do that. Post textual information as text, not as images. Images can't be searched, images can be hard to read for visually impaired people, images can't be compiled, etc.
